# Problems with the Google Earth Internal Browser using GWT pages

Tags: gwt, fragment-identifier, http-get

Good afternoon,

I'm developing a google-earth web application, where users can use the desktop Google Earth program to perform searches.

One problem I'm running into is that, when the Internal Browser tries to hit a GWT page I have written, with parameters in it, the Internal Browser seems to just drop the second set of parameters.

As an example an URL of:

http://mysite.com/Client/?entryPoint=start#paramater=1

Becomes:

http://mysite.com/Client/?entryPoint=start

Any idea how I can work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is due to the hash being used as the delimiter for the queries. http get queries are encoded using ? and & like so.

```
http://mysite.com/Client/?entryPoint=start&paramater=1
```

The hash is reserved as the url fragment identifier.

If, for some unknown reason you can't change the query delimitation then you could just use the first parameter and add your own delimitation syntax. For example.

```
http://mysite.com/Client/?entryPoint=start_paramater=1_foo=bar_etc=0
```

You would then just split the single parameter on the chosen delimiter (in this case the underscrore _) then again  in to variable/value pairs by splitting on the equals sign (=)